# how to place an label on top of screen which showing an error

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

```
'''<second>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        size:root.width,root.height
        padding:75
        spacing:20
        BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        text:"player 1"
                        font_size: sp(30)
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1.25}
        Button:
            on_press:root.rock()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'pvp2'
            text:"rock"
            Image:
                source:'rock.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y-160
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
        Button:
            on_press:root.scissor()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'pvp2'
            text:"scissor"
            Image:
                source:'scissor.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y-160
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
        Button:
            on_press:root.paper()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'pvp2'
            text:"paper"
            Image:
                source:'paper.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y-160
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False '''
```

there is an error popping up:
if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

so how to place the label on top the screen which is under double box layout
to note:
that this is only partial code as this where the error is occuring so i didnt paste the full
code if you do have the solution but need the full code you just ask i dont mind sharing as it
is my second time asking an question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can reproduce the problem from this

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when your kivy file has **wrong Indentations**.

if that really was your code, see the line 8-11 of your code, that has too much indentations on it.

**EDIT:**

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size:root.width,root.height
    padding:75
    spacing:20
    Label:
        text:"player 1"
        font_size: sp(30)
        size_hint_y: 0.1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        Button:
            on_press:root.rock()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'pvp2'
            text:"rock"
            Image:
                source:'rock.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y-160
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
        Button:
            on_press:root.scissor()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'pvp2'
            text:"scissor"
            Image:
                source:'scissor.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y-160
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
        Button:
            on_press:root.paper()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'pvp2'
            text:"paper"
            Image:
                source:'paper.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y-160
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False '''
```

Please also note the **size_hint_y.**
you may want to adjust it. And also no need to add pos_hint now.

Comment: I fixed all the indents the problem is still there for some reason if I want add another box layout at the top like at line 8 I can't do that for some reason as the error none type is not subscriptable

Comment: For now I pushed at the bottom used a floatlayout with pos hint it is working as I wanted it but i still wanted to know why was that not working

Comment: now i see your problem. The root boxlay out is actually oriented "horizontally". you cant put that label you are saying on top. If you want to see the label on top see my next answer.

Comment: I can't see you're next answer, can u send a link

Comment: It's right here too. see the EDIT.

Comment: Ah yes I understand now and this is much better as it helps in placement itself, thank you so much